# MERN deployed to heroku - app feature is not working

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have MERN app and i have deployed it on heroku. build and deploy without errors or issues. App is live and i can register and log in. But problem is after login or register you are redirected to `/home` components which is displaying polls. **on my development enviroment everything is working fine. But after deployment on heroku it is not**. And issue is that componet is not loading and console error is

```
  TypeError: n.map is not a function
    at t.value (Polls.jsx:23)
    at ci (react-dom.production.min.js:3418)
    at ui (react-dom.production.min.js:3409)
    at mi (react-dom.production.min.js:3593)
    at qi (react-dom.production.min.js:4600)
    at $i (react-dom.production.min.js:4620)
    at Aa (react-dom.production.min.js:5017)
    at Da (react-dom.production.min.js:4983)
    at Ma (react-dom.production.min.js:4927)
    at Qi (react-dom.production.min.js:4847)
wi @ react-dom.production.min.js:3843
polls.js:29 


Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
        at polls.js:29
        at w (runtime.js:63)
        at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:282)
        at Generator.t.(anonymous function) [as next] (https://floating-island-91400.herokuapp.com/static/js/1.3d3fa28b.chunk.js:1:218826)
        at r (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
        at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
```

so if i go to Polls.jsx line 23 it is saying that poll.map is not a function where poll is coming form redux so i am assumig that this data is not fetched.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getPolls, getUserPolls, getCurrentPoll } from "../store/actions";

class Polls extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getPolls } = this.props;
    getPolls();
  }

  handleSelect(id) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push(`/poll/${id}`);
  }
  render() {
    const { polls, auth, getPolls, getUserPolls } = this.props;
      **//this line is saying that polls.map is not a function**
    const allPolls = polls.map(poll => (
      <li
        className="single-poll"
        onClick={() => this.handleSelect(poll._id)}
        key={poll._id}
      >
        {poll.question}
      </li>
    ));
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <div>
            <button className="polls-btn" onClick={getPolls}>
              All Polls
            </button>
            <button className="polls-btn" onClick={getUserPolls}>
              My Polls
            </button>
            <ul className="polls">{allPolls}</ul>
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  polls: state.polls
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getPolls,
    getUserPolls,
    getCurrentPoll
  }
)(Polls);
```

polls.js is refering to

```
export const getPolls = () => {
return async dispatch => {
    try {
        const polls = await api.call('get', 'poll')
        dispatch(setPolls(polls))
        dispatch(removeError())
    } catch (err) {
        const
            error = err.response.data;
        dispatch(addError(error.message));
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: As you stated, the data isn't being fetched and you can't map an undefined. Go to your dev console in the browser. Select the "Network" tab and make sure the subtab "XHR" or "All" is selected. This will log all requests.  Log into your app in production, and check and make sure it's showing up AND is connecting to the correct destination. If it isn't showing up, then clear your browser cache and cookies and try again. I suspect the problem might be the `ServiceWorker` (if so, remove it from your app)

Comment: @mattcarlotta added screenshot from network

Comment: i deployed with unregistered service worker and no i can even see dashboard...

Comment: Well I see a `poll` request, but it's status is 304, which means nothing changed. So if you're still getting that same error, then it sounds like there's no data to be fetched. You could mitigate the crash by simply putting in conditional rendering: If there aren't `polls` render a `No polls found` component, and if there are `polls` render them. Out of curiosity, how are you integrating `mongo`? Through `mLab mongo`?

Comment: yes mlab/moongose. I was thinking about to have if() to say if not data redner spinner. maybe the problem is that componet is rendered before data is fetched.
but it doesn't explain why on dev server is working

Comment: Does your dev server already have `polls` data present? Either way, this needs to be handled conditionally (a spinner is decent, but if there's no data to be displayed, then you need to convey this to the user, instead of just showing an infinite spinner). For example: https://i.imgur.com/07a9dgE.png

Comment: actualy on m dev server when there is no polls home compoent is rendered beacue home is a parent for polls so it has it own buttons to be displayed